# How to hide text from Mapbox GL JS tooltips when it is null?

Tags: javascript, html, mapbox-gl-js

I've created a map in mapbox GL JS, but cannot hide the tooltip content when the value is null.
[Example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK4wW.png)
Here is the full code: https://github.com/Ninlin/irystory/blob/main/index.html

I tried the following, but the if-statement does not work and removes the tooltip completely. What should I modify?

```
popup
    .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
    .setHTML("<h3>" + name + "</h3>" +
    "<h4 id ='fn'>" + full_name + '</h4>')
    .addTo(map);

if (full_name != null) {
document.getElementById('fn').style.display = 'block';
} else {
document.getElementById('fn').style.display = 'none';
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing, `full_name` is actually a string, so this seems to be working:

```js
if (full_name != "null") {
    popup
      .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
      .setHTML("<h3>" + name + "</h3>" +
        '<hr>' +
        "<h4>" + full_name + '</h4>' +
        '<h4>' + birth + '-' + death + '</h4>' +
        '<p>'+occupation+'</p>')
      .addTo(map);
}
```